# How can I create an view to insert information in SwiftData that includes an optional Date field and uses the Date Picker

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, swift-data

I have a SwiftData model that includes an optional date.

I want to create a view to insert information into that model and use the DatePicker for the date.

Since a DatePicker can't be blank, I assume I have to use an onTapGesture or something to hide the DatePicker until the user indicates they want to associate a date with the item. But first I have to get around the errors I keep encountering.

The current set up I have is giving this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Date?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Date>'`

Here is my Model:

```
import SwiftData

@Model
class Item {
    var name: String
    var date: Date? = nil
    

    init(name: String, date: Date?) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far in the view to add information:

```
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    //Display the list of categories added
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    @State private var newItem = Item(name: "", date: Date?.none)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List{
            Section("Add item"){
                TextField("Enter Name", text: $newItem.name)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Select Date")
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus")
                    if let date = $newItem.date {
                        DatePicker("Date", selection: date)
                    }
                }
```

The binding date error is on the last line with the DatePicker.

I've seen suggestions on optional dates around, but they predate SwiftData and I'm new to coding so I'm not able to make the translation from those solutions to a working version with my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing special just because you use SwiftData, the above linked question will answer your question.